# PIL posterize- fix green pixels

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I decided to write my own posterize function in PIL instead of using the provided one so that I could understand it more.

## Problem

Sometimes, unexpected green pixels show up when using my posterize function that don't when using the built-in posterize function.

## Example

[image: mine]
[image: theirs]

The first picture is the input and output of my posterize function to 4 levels. The second one is the input and output of the built-in posterize function.

#### Closeup

[image: detail]

## How mine works

My posterize function works by figuring out thresholds, using bisect_left to put each element of a RGB tuple into a slot, and reassigning it the threshold value, like so.

```
def posterize(im, levels):

    #Figure out thresholds for the pixel colors
    increment = 255//levels
    thresholds = range(1, 256, increment)
    
    im = copy.copy(im)
    img = im.load()
    #Iterate through the image
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        for x in range(im.size[0]):

            #Get a new RGB tuple based on thresholds
            new = []
            for c in range(3):
                color = img[x, y][c]
                level = bisect_left(thresholds, color)-1
                new.append(thresholds[level])

            #Put the new pixel on the image
            img[x, y] = tuple(new)
    
    #Return the image
    return im
```

Anyway, can someone explain why this returns green pixels, and how to fix it? If possible, I would like to still use an approach similar to mine, if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `bisect_left` almost correctly... almost.

If you read the documentation, you'll notice how `bisect` takes `lo` and `hi` parameters, which are set to `0` and `len(arr)` respectively. To work around `IndexError`, you add -1 to the result. But this will map results that should be `0` to `len-1`, since indexing `arr[-1]` in Python is the same as indexing `arr[len(arr)-1]`. And indeed, if you look closely - the green pixels should have their green channel set to 0, but they get 255 because of the -1 wraparound.

That is the source of your green pixels.

The fix is simple - instead of doing:

```
bisect_left(thresholds, color)-1
```

do

```
bisect_left(thresholds, color, lo=0, hi=len(thresholds)-1)
```

and that's all. At the same time, **you'll notice how the pictures have their brightness set correctly as well**, since because of `-1` the are darker than they should be.